# Tracking user activity in Java EE

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

I would like to track user's sessions. I am interested in getting the user logname, context he accessed and the time when he accessed a certain context.

I was thinking of using a class that implements HttpSessionListener (overriding sessionCreated(final HttpSessionEvent se) and sessionDestroyed(final HttpSessionEvent se)) but on these methods I don't get access to the request (from where I could pull the user's logname and context he accessed).

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As per my knowledge, sessionCreated and sessionDestroyed will be invoked when user logs in and logs out.. how can this be used to track  the contexts he accessed during his time on the session?

Comment: I was wondering if I could get context info in sessionCreated and sessionDestroyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a servlet [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) is more suitable for what you want. I suggest to write a custom filter around all the urls you want to track.

In the `doFilter()` method you have access to the `HttpServletRequest` as needed. From the request object you can get `HttpSession` too.

Here is an example:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class TrackingFilter implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = config;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, 
              FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        String loggedInUser = "Unregistered user";

        //assuming you have a session attribute named user with the username
        if(session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
            loggedInUser = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
        }

        Date accessedDate = new Date();
        filterConfig.getServletContext().log(
                String.format("%s accessed context %s on %tF %tT",
                        loggedInUser, request.getRequestURI() , 
                              accessedDate, accessedDate)
        );

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

See also: [JavaEE6 tutorial section about filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html).

Comment: I was considering a Filter ... expecting for a couple of more ideas and then I'll decide in one direction or the other.

Thanks !

Comment: @Sergiu It's not going to get better than a filter. dcernahoschi, some sample code would make your answer better